# Bounty for answers within the bounty period

Tags: feature-request, answers, bounty, featured-questions

I was wondering if this is an intentional behavior or something that maybe needs to be change.

When a question is offered a bounty, and an answer is given during the bounty period, shouldn't that answer be awarded with the bounty if is selected as the correct answer even if it is after the bounty period?

Maybe a question got attention during this bounty period, it was answered but the author forgot about it or just was busy and couldn't select it as the correct answer in time. Then the answer (that was encouraged somehow by the bounty) will not receive as much reward.

Am I wrong in how the bounty system does/should work? 
If I am right, is there any plan into changing this?

Comment: Don't forget that the person offering the bounty may not be the person who asked the question. :)

Comment: @catija sorry, I forgot also that case, in any way, I think it is more related with the time period when they answer

Comment: This blog post is very old but it may answer some of your questions... I don't know that it answers this one, though: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

Comment: What do you mean by "selected as the correct answer"? The tick for "accepted" is not related to correctness (and I have seen several accepted answer which are far from being correct). It is exclusively only about which answer OP found most helpful. Correctness can better (though not perfectly) be judged by upvotes.

Comment: Sorry for my vague definition, the accepted answer is the one I considered correct, since is the one that addresses the question in the best way (helpful, useful, accuracy...). Anyhow, my question was not about what is a correct answer or not, is rather that if an answer has been accepted by the OP and this answer was given during bounty period, should the system give the bounty away? And if not, why not?

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answers mean something **only** to the OP who marked it as "accepted".  They bear no value otherwise, which extends to:

- accuracy
- correctness
- general helpfulness
- usefulness
- portability
- coherence (e.g. I've seen answers accepted which don't make *sense*)

...so allowing a bounty to be awarded to an accepted answer would then suddenly give accepted answers more meaning than they should, which would be *very* bad.

<sup>Also, the OP is informed of a bounty expiring in several ways.  If they come back within a *week* of the bounty being started, they'll know.  If they have email notification, they'll know.  If they accept an answer a day later, then *why* they haven't decided to award the bounty is between them and whatever godforsaken schedule they have to keep.</sup>

Comment: I think you missunderstood. Is not about awarding answers JUST because they were done during the bounty period, is about, if an answer is mark as correct (hence they have bear value with accuracy, correctness, general helpfulness...) AND this answer was published during the bounty period, the answer should get the bounty even though it was mark as an answer well after. Anyother way I can bounty a question to draw answers to it and then never give the bounty to answers that saw the question because of the bounty for example.

Comment: @SirPeople: First, someone other than the question's OP can offer a bounty, so it only is meaningful if the OP and the bounty offerer are the same. Second, why should the bounty be awarded for any reason after the bounty period has elapsed?

Comment: @SirPeople: "*Anyother way I can bounty a question to draw answers to it and then never give the bounty to answers that saw the question because of the bounty for example.*" If the person offering the bounty does not award one, the system will give half the bounty to the highest voted answer posted within the bounty period, but only if the question has at least +2 votes. So if the bounty attracted a good answer, someone will get it.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it makes more sense if the OP and the bounty offerer are the same person. Secondly,I never said that the bounty should be awarded for any reason, just if the answer is accepted and if the answer has been published in bounty period (Because eventhough the bounty period has expired, the answer was in time)

I didnt know those details of your last comment, thanks.